# Ruby-on-Rails : how to display all "rake:about" data inside a Rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I would like to display the output of "rake:about" inside a Rails view.

Or all equivalent data into a view.

Is it feasible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Backticks to execute system command. So inside view it would look like:

```
<%= `rake about` %>
```

Answer (score 4):

`rake about` is merely outputting the value of `Rails::Info.to_s` to stdout. You can thus use this data directly from Rails without invoking `rake` (neither inline nor via a shellout):

```
<%= Rails::Info.to_s %>
```

Since the data is intended for display in a text console, it is not directly suitable for HTML output. You can make it more readable by requesting HTML output with

```
<%= raw Rails::Info.to_html %>
```

or by just wrapping the whole block in `<pre>` tags so that it is shown similar to how it would look on the console:

```
<pre>
  <%= Rails::Info.to_s %>
</pre>
```

Finally, if you want to format the details yourself, you can get the raw properties shown by `Rails::Info` as an array of arrays with

```
Rails::Info.properties
```